# Escaping " in NSString stringWithFormat is being goofy

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, nested, stringwithformat

I use

```
NSString *copyCommand=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"put \"%@\" \"%@\"",sourceEscaped,destinationDirectory];
```

but the actual NSString includes the \

For example, if sourceEscaped=test and destinationDirectory=test I expect the NSString to contain:

```
put "test" "test"
```

and not

```
put \"test\" \"test\"
```

Note the directoryCommand in the example below:

[image]

Comment: Your question is unclear. which "\" are you referring to? What are the input strings (`storageID`, `destinationDirectory`, `sourceEscaped`), and what output do you expect? When you say "highly inconsistent," in what way is it inconsistent?

Comment: Updated for clarity

Comment: That is just the debugger view, which escapes the quotation marks inside the string. Use `NSLog(@"cmd=%@", directoryCommand)` to verify, or try `po directoryCommand` in the debugger console.

Comment: @MartinR actually your comment is an answer, probably you should write it as answer to close this question.

Comment: Agree - it does answer it.